# Including html with script, require not defined

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm building electron app that allows extendable modules. I'm getting require not defined when i call it from loaded html script. How can i do this or what approach can i take to deal with this?

I've html loaded into iframe on click. Html has script tag with what module has to do.

mainWindow.html

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>

<script>
var moduleOrange = document.querySelector('.module-orange')
      moduleOrange.addEventListener('click', addScript);
 function addScript(e) {
 var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
        frame.setAttribute("src", "orange.html");
 }
</script>
```

orange.html

```
<script>
require('puppeteer')
</script>
```

I want included html script to have separate functionality, without need of calling every method from mainWindow.html.

Comment: [`nodeIntegration` must be enabled when you create a `BrowserWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)

Comment: @hijleh I already did this, i have had this problem earlier. This is different problem